# Can I force MySql table name case sensitivity on file systems that aren't case sensitive

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

So our target environment is linux, making mysql case-sensitive by default.  I am aware that we can make our linux environment not case sensitive with the lower_case_table_names variable, but we would rather not.  We have a few times been bitten with a case mismatch because our dev rigs are OSX, and mysql is not case sensitive there.

Is there a way we can force table names to be case sensitive on my OSX install of MySql (5.0.83 if that matters) so that we catch a table name case mismatch prior to deploying to the integration servers running on linux?

Comment: Commenting to subscribe. per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/subscribing-to-questions-and-comments-that-dont-belong-to-you

Answer (score 2):

Set `lower_case_table_names=0` in `my.cnf`.

If you installed via homebrew, the file is here:
`/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/<version>/my.cnf`

Queries with tables should now be case sensitive:

`mysql> select count(*) from user;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'xxx.user' doesn't exist
mysql> select count(*) from User;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: This seems like it should work, but it doesn't for me with mysql@5.7 and MacOS Mojave 10.14.4.

Answer (score -1):

The best thing to do here is fix your table names so that there aren't any conflicts. Differentiating solely by case is a bad idea, and leads to confusion (as you probably know).

But try using single quote marks around the table names during creation. This works on SUSE/Linux/MySQL 5.0 with the query browser running on windows.

```
CREATE TABLE  `MySchema`.`test` (
  `COMMENT` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE  `MySchema`.`Test` (
  `COMMENT` text
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into MySchema.test values ('this is table test' );
insert into MySchema.Test values ('this is table Test' );


select * from MySchema.test;
select * from MySchema.Test;
```

Do you want it to fail if a non-case sensitive client requests a table using the wrong case? I believe it should fail if the MySQL database is running on Linux.

Check out [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)
"One notable exception is Mac OS X, which is Unix-based but uses a default file system type (HFS+) that is not case sensitive. However, Mac OS X also supports UFS volumes, which are case sensitive just as on any Unix."

Comment: Our table names do not conflict. But sometimes we have code which miscapitalizes table names, and the case-insensitive nature of the default OS X filesystem means that we don't see the bug until we deploy to linux.